# How many flags to you need to reach each rank in your secret base?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

In secret bases you can collect a flag of each new secret base you find. I've noticed some bases have different color flags, which I assume means a different rank. How many flags to you need to get a new rank (silver rank, etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

I found the list of ranks by number of flags obtained on [GameFAQs forums](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/792673-pokemon-omega-ruby/70644824):

> **Secret Base Guild Rank Rewards:**
>
> **Bronze Rank** - 30 Flags - Blackboard
>
> **Silver Rank** - 100 Flags - Jukebox
>
> **Gold Rank** - 500 Flags - Mood Lighting
>
> **Platinum Rank** - 1,000 Flags - Confetti and Garchompite

Comment: Oh wow, you get rewards? O.O Thanks so much!